# How to shedule a time base query? in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I am using this query to update a status value

```php
public function updateStatus(Request $request)
{
    $customer = Customer::findOrFail($request->user_id);
    $customer->status = $request->status;
    $customer->new_customer_status = 1;
    $customer->save();
    return response()->json(['message' => 'User status updated successfully.']);
}
```

I want that if `status == 1` then after one week `$customer->new_customer_status` should automatically becomes `NULL`

How can I schedule time or days based query that run automatically after one week or at a given time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make a command with `php artisan make:command UpdateUserNotNew`
2. inside that class app/Console/Commands/UpdateUserNotNew.php set the command name:

   `protected $signature = 'cron:update-user-not-new';`

   under handle method:

---

```
public function handle()
{
    Customer::whereDate('created_at', '>', now()->addDays(7)->toDateTimeString())
        ->update([
            'new_customer_status' => null
        ]);
}
```

---

3. inside app/Console/Kernel.php under `schedule()` method add this line:

---

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('cron:update-user-not-new')->daily();  //<--- this line
}
```

---

In order all of that to work you must have the crontab enabled on your server, that info is in Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling#introduction

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your query inside a queued job. Then, you can schedule this job to run after one week.

This is the example given in the documentation, right here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#delayed-dispatching

```php
ProcessPodcast::dispatch($podcast)->delay(now()->addMinutes(10));
```

Where `ProcessPodcast` is the job class. I'll let you dive further in the documentation to see how to create a job but it's really easy and straightforward. Of course, in your case, you should probably do `now()->addWeek()` instead of `now()->addMinutes(10)`.